# Nest js packaging hangs at build process of the serverless framework

Tags: nestjs, serverless-framework

So i did a fresh install of nestjs application and i am trying to add the serverless framework with it.I also added few of the packages to support the serverless framework

```
{
  "name": "n1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.17",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.6",
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.3.8",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "serverless-offline": "^6.5.0",
    "serverless-plugin-optimize": "^4.1.4-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

and i have also added the serverless.yml file which is pointing in to lambda.handler

serverless.yml file

```
service:
 name: nest-serverless-framework

plugins:
 - '@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript'
 - serverless-plugin-optimize
 - serverless-offline

provider:
 name: aws
 runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
 main:
   handler: src/lambda.handler
   events:
     - http:
         method: any
         path: /{any+}
```

So the handler file is simple it just exported a module that can bootstrap the application

```
import { Handler, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { createServer, proxy } from 'aws-serverless-express';
import { eventContext } from 'aws-serverless-express/middleware';

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import express from 'express';

const binaryMimeTypes: string[] = [];

let cachedServer: Server;

// Create the Nest.js server and convert it into an Express.js server
async function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Server> {
    if (!cachedServer) {
        const expressApp = express();
        const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new
        ExpressAdapter(expressApp))
        nestApp.use(eventContext());
        await nestApp.init();
        cachedServer = createServer(expressApp, undefined,
            binaryMimeTypes);
    }
    return cachedServer;
}

// Export the handler : the entry point of the Lambda function
export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
    cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
    return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
}
```

but when i now try to do `sls offline start`, the computer just hangs and nothing happen and i have to restart the computer forcefully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to deploy and see what error occurs on AWS. Maybe it helps you to fix on local. (I'm just suggesting this because your computer hangs).

Comment: SLS deploy also has a packaging step . So basically the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with v8 crashing during the serverless build. Changing packages from @hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript to the original serverless-plugin-typescript fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [aws-serverless-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-serverless-express) says:

> *On 11/30* [2022]*, the AWS Serverless Express library is moving to Vendia and will be rebranded to serverless-express [...]*

has become obsolete.

Probably the same job, you wanted to achieve, does the following Vendina example:

[vendia serveless basic-starter-nestjs](https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express/tree/mainline/examples/basic-starter-nestjs)